# connecting sql server Database via apcahe logged in user

Tags: php, laravel, database, windows, authentication

I am trying to connect SQL server via windows authentication. Apache is logged in with AD service account. with the same AS service account trying to connect database from Apache server. but getting select permission was denied error. screen shot is attached for reference. but I am able to connect DB and I am able to run queries with the same service account with windows authentication in SSMS.

[image]

Please help me to resolve this issue. Need to connect db with the service account from PHP Laravel using windows authentication instead of SQL server authentication.

Comment: You've unhelpfully posted the error as a picture (see [ask] where it specifically tells you not to do that), and (even more unhelpfully) truncated it so that we can't see all the important details, but from what little we can see the error seems to be about the lack of specific permissions on a specific object in the database, not an issue with logging in to the SQL server.